# difference between 'def' and no 'def'

Tags: function, gradle, groovy

I am a groovy beginner.
I am confused that whether 'def' is used.

```
def str = "hello"
print str
```

vs

```
str = "hello"
print str
```

From this example. the result is same.But I wonder if they are different.
And  are there other situations are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second example is only valid if you are working with scripts. See [3.2 Script class here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/structure.html).

Without def variable is stored in Script's binding, and works as a "global" variable in that script.

If you define variable with `def` it will be a local variable of Script's `run` method, and follow all rules of local variable. This difference doesn't really matter if you work with one script.

Difference can be illustrated with following snippet:

```
def closureA = { println(a) }
def closureB = { println(b) }

a = "I'm global"
def b = "I'm local"

println(a) // prints "I'm global"
println(b) // prints "I'm local"

closureA() // prints "I'm global"  
closureB() // throws groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: b
```

Here I first declare 2 closures (anonymous functions). Note, that at declaration time neither `a` nor `b` is declared, and therefore not accessible for closures. It's fine.

Then I call `println` directly after declaration, and in that case I'm in the same scope with both `a` and `b`. I'm able to print their value.

Next I call closures. Both closure check local scope, and if variable is not found there, they check `bindings`. And here is the difference: `a` is accessible, while `b` - not.

Comment: Seagull, Thank you very much !